# Русские названия животных

Tags: этимология

Некоторые тут уже обсуждались (лошадь, собака, кошка). Объяснение слова "зубр" как краткое прилагательное от "зубастый", "имеющий зубы (рога)" мне показалось сомнительным. Равно, как и "волк" от "тащить волоком".
А вот, например, "лось" и "лиса" происходят ли от слова "лес"? А как быть, например, с зайцем? Или косулей (что она косит или почему косая?). А олень, насколько я знаю, изначально вообще было именем.
В общем, кто что знает о происхождении названий этих животных?

Answer (score 3):

**О лисе. Информация из интернета.** Происходит от праслав. , от кот. в числе прочего произошли: ст.-слав. лиса (др.-греч. ἀλώπηξ), русск. лис, лиса, укр. лис, лисиця, болг. лисица, сербохорв. ли̑с, лѝсица, словенск. lìs (род. п. lísa, lisíca), др.-чешск. lisa, чешск. liška, польск. lis, lisica, в.-луж., н.-луж. liška. Отсюда же лисичка — название гриба, диал. лисый «желтоватый», залисеть «приобрести желтоватый оттенок», череповецк. Гадательно возведение к *vleipso-(-sā) и сближение с лат. volpēs, vulpēs (подобно* krivъ: лат. curvus) и далее — с латышск. lарsа, лит. lãpė, др.-прусск. lаре, греч. ἀλώπηξ. Использованы данные словаря М. Фасмера;

**Там же и о зайце есть немного**.